# Add padding above Button Text

Tags: android, text, button

How can I add some padding between the button and its text?

[image]

```
        <Button
            android:text="@string/routes_btn_title"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/temp_button_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use android:drawablePadding in your layout.